# Como posso simular um placeholder utilizando uma 'label'?

Tags: css, html, label, placeholder, formulário

Estou tentando fazer com que o `label` simule um placeholder fixo.

A maior dificuldade é alterar as propriedades do `label` quando o `input` recebe o `focus`, e o `input` preencher o resto do espaço automaticamente.

Tentei usar a mesma técnica do `float:left` com `overflow:hidden`, mas não funcionou.

Teria como fazer isso usando apenas CSS?

**HTML**

```html
<article>
  <form>
    <label>Qualquer nome para qualquer tamanho</label>
    <input>
  </form>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  font-family: arial;
}
article{
  margin: 5% 0 0 4%;
  width: 50%;
}
label{
  float: left;
  padding: 2%;
  background: #ccc;
  line-heigt: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius-right: 3px;
}
form{
  width: 100%;
}
input{
  display: block;
  padding: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
}
input:focus{
  background: #999;
}
```

[**Código no CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjdDv)

Comment: O input deveria ficar na frente da label?

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara para mim, dá para explicar melhor? Quer ter o label por cima (na frente) do input, e desaparecer quando o input receber focus?

Comment: O label irá ficar antes do input. 
Quero deixar o label como tivesse dentro do input. 
Simulando um placeholder.

Comment: Não compreendo que que quer dizer com "antes" e "como tivesse dentro do input". Tendo um elemento por cima com por exemplo z-index superior não deixa clicar no elemento que está por baixo para fazer focus.

Comment: Ainda estou confuso sobre o que você deseja fazer, tente desenhar no post utilizando caracteres box drawing [(link Wikipédia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)

Comment: Alterei o CSS para entender melhor.

Comment: Alterei o css e deixei com um estilo mais agradável. Ao clicar no input eu gostaria de modificar o background do label, para ele parecer que é o mesmo campo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não estou a ver como fazer isto só com CSS uma vez que você quer alterar um elemento quando fizer `focus`no outro e eles não tendo entre si grau de parentesco.

Assim, a minha sugestão é usar javascript. Aqui fica um exemplo, se tiver uma biblioteca como [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) ou [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) posso adaptar o código para essa biblioteca.

```js
var label = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0];
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

label.onclick = function () {
    label.style.display = 'none';
    input.focus();
};
input.onblur = function () {
    if(!this.value) label.style.display = 'block';
};
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/estUk/)

Answer (score 11):

Pode-se utilizar os seletores complexos adjacentes, já que ambos os elementos ( `input` e `label`) compartilham o mesmo elemento pai: `form`. Entretanto, há uma única e simples condição: o elemento `input` deve preceder `label`.

Nesse seu caso, você pode escolher entre usar o **seletor irmão adjacente (+)** e **seletor adjacente geral (~)**. A diferença entre os dois é que o adjacente geral é mais flexível quanto à posição do elemento filho após seu irmão. Caso pareça confuso, escrevi [um artigo bem completo](https://diessi.ca/blog/desmitificando-seletores-complexos/) sobre o funcionamento dos seletores.

Apesar da flexibilidade do seletor adjacente geral (CSS3), costumo optar pelo seletor irmão adjacente, por ser do CSS 2.1. A solução é simples:

```css
input:focus, input:focus + label {
  /* estilo */
}
```

E os problemas de posicionamento acarretados pela "condição" podem ser resolvidos com a propriedade `float`.

[**Veja o resultado no JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/isUpipA/1/edit), em que simplifiquei e organizei a solução.

Comment: +1 por citar artigo próprio artigo. Muito boa explicação!